# CSS3 - why is my transform not working?

Tags: html, css

I've been using CSS3 transitions fine but this is the first `transform` I've tried and it doesn't seem to play by the same rules. (note: I'm just testing in `-moz` for now....)

What I'm trying to achieve:

- on hover of a `li` it's child `.feat_tt` animates down 20px
- on de-hover i want it to revert to its original position

My code:

```
.feat_tt { top: -180px; -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;}
.feat_props li:hover .feat_tt { -moz-transform: translate(0, 20px); }
```

What happens:

- The animation runs on the first `.feat_tt` you hover.
- On de-hover, the position does not revert
- hovering another `.feat_tt` after the first one, it's as if the animation has already been performed. (they are in separate `li`'s)

---

here is some sample html i'm using this on:

```
<ul class="feat_props">
    <li>
        <p>Barsham West Barns</p>
        <div class="feat_tt">Sleeps 44 people mofo!</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Barsham West Barns</p>
        <div class="feat_tt">Sleeps 44 people mofo!</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Barsham West Barns</p>
        <div class="feat_tt">Sleeps 44 people mofo!</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: seems to work on mouseover and mouseout, http://jsfiddle.net/6SwDk/ (using Firefox 6)

Comment: It's not the most pretty looking thing, but it seems to do what you are asking. All I did was move your code line by line and it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/b3AEf/ Can you explain what it's doing that it's not supposed to? It seems to move back on "dehover".

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on Firefox 5. All I did was dump everything you wrote into an HTML5 page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.feat_tt { top: -180px; -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;}
.feat_props li:hover .feat_tt { -moz-transform: translate(0, 20px); }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="feat_props">
<li>
    <p>Barsham West Barns</p>
    <div class="feat_tt">Sleeps 44 people!</div>
</li>
<li>
    <p>Barsham West Barns</p>
    <div class="feat_tt">Sleeps 44 people!</div>
</li>
<li>
    <p>Barsham West Barns</p>
    <div class="feat_tt">Sleeps 44 people!</div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

For information on usage of the CSS3 property transform you can check http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp